# GenMyModel Relational DB

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, modeling, xmi

I want to generate a Relational DB model from GenMyModel.
However, it seems that only stanard XMI files can be exported. I searched about XMI but i didn't get the point and i still want to try GenMyModel.
Maybe generate XMI from SQL? how?

Comment: You want to take a GenMyModel Relational DB model and generate SQL code or to take SQL code and generate a Relational DB model from it?

Comment: I want to generate a Relational DB model from SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I work at GenMyModel

At the moment, GenMyModel cannot take a SQL schema and reverse it to Relational DB model. We are working on some solutions, and we currently have a very nice and flexible result, but it is not yet in production. We hope we will be able to release it very soon!